# von Neumann algebra and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is any matrix algebra regular in the sence of von Neuman? if yes could you tell me about any paper talk about this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ring $R$ is Von Neumann regular if $\forall a\in R$ there exists $x\in R$ such that $a=axa$. 
We can show that the ring of all $n\times n$ matrices over a regular ring is regular. You can find the proof in: *K.R. Goodearl , Von Neumann regular Rings,* pag. 4.

Answer (score 2):

If my "matrix algebra" you mean $M_n(F)$ for some field $F$, then yes. Such a ring is semisimple, meaning that every right ideal is a direct summand. You can show that a ring $R$ is von Neumann regular iff every finitely generated right ideal of $R$ is a direct summand of $R$.

In fact, you can even show that $M_n(S)$ is von Neumann regular for any von Neumann regular ring $S$. There are a lot of ways to do this, but the ones that come to mind immediately for me are all categorical. This is because von Neumann regularity is a Morita invariant property, and hence it will be preserved by matrix rings. You could learn about this in textbooks like Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings* or Anderson and Fuller's *Rings and categories of modules*, although they are speaking more generally, not just about von Neumann regular rings.

Of course, there are algebras of matrices that aren't von Neumann regular: for example, you have the upper triangular matrices $T_n(F)$ for any $n>2$. It has a nonzero nilpotent ideal, but a von Neumann regular ring will never have such an ideal.